# Linux terminal output redirection

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

I want to redirect the output of a bash script to a file.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "recursive c"
for ((i=0;i<=20;i+=1)); do
time ./recursive
done
```

But if I run it like this:

```
script.sh >> temp.txt
```

only the output of ./recursive will be captured in the file.

I want to capture the output of time command in the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`:

```
script.sh >> temp.txt  2>&1
```

Or if using `bash` 4.0:

```
$ script.sh &>> temp.txt
```

(Thanks for the second form go to commenter ephemient.  I can't verify as I have an earlier `bash`.)

---

My tests were surprising:

```
$ time sleep 1 > /dev/null 2>&1

real    0m1.036s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.032s
```

The problem is the redirection was included as part of the command to be timed.  Here was the solution for this test:

```
$ (time sleep 1) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I don't think this is part of your problem, but it seemed worth a mention.

Comment: New in bash 4.0: `script.sh &>> temp.txt` does the same as above.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the &>> method better, but this is a solution as well:

```
$ script.sh 2>&1 |tee -a temp.txt
```

Comment: Yep, me too. You can view the output in console and have it in the file too.