# Stop exec and telnet from showing login outputs

Tags: linux

I have script that access module locally using the code

```
exec 3<> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5037 ; echo -e "my command here" >&3 ; cat <&3
```

In the telnet session, I got the lines

```
Remote connection from 127.0.0.1:51698 to 127.0.0.1:5037
Closing connection to 127.0.0.1:51698
```

These outputs appears also with telnet sessions (without script)

How can I stop them as the script is running multiple timer per min and is spamming the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux terminal output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588144/linux-terminal-output-redirection)

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect it in a .txt file.

This might help you:

```
 your_command > log.txt 2>&1
```

This will leave your console clean while all the logs will be saved on log.txt

Comment: If you don't want to see any output (stdout or stderr) and don't care at all about it  then

```your_command >/dev/null 2>&1```

Comment: @avivl not the best idea

Comment: I  am able to put the outputs in a file, the problem is the logs are appearing in the telnet session and spamming the log file. Is there a way to have my command outputs in a file , and stop the spam on the telnet? - Thanks

Comment: @Nsh the command I showed you before in the post should do what you are looking at. I'm surprised that it still spams the telnet session with logs :o

Comment: I replaced echo -e "my command here" >&3 with  2>&1 ,, it printed in the telnet , I got outputs in the linux terminal and it didn't exit from the command until I made ctrl + c